# SOAPUI assert json response if equals to json

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I have in my TestCase 'CheckResult' where I am calling my service, and I have set of 36 same pieces like this:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
        "idCalculation": 111,
        "idCalculationResult": 707,
        "exchangeRate": 120.3,
        "interestRate": 4.2,
        "anuityDomesticCurrencyAmount": 165669.9171,
        "anuityForeignCurrencyAmount": 1377.1397,
        "totalDomesticCurrencyAmount": 11554978.0125,
        "totalForeignCurrencyAmount": 96051.355,
        "dti": 0.6036
    },
    {
        "idCalculation": 111,
        "idCalculationResult": 708,
        "exchangeRate": 120.3,
        "interestRate": 4.7,
        "anuityDomesticCurrencyAmount": 183875.1364,
        "anuityForeignCurrencyAmount": 1528.4716,
        "totalDomesticCurrencyAmount": 11991903.275,
        "totalForeignCurrencyAmount": 99683.3189,
        "dti": 0.5438
    },
    {
        "idCalculation": 111,
        "idCalculationResult": 709,
        "exchangeRate": 120.3,
        "interestRate": 5.2,
        "anuityDomesticCurrencyAmount": 202349.3784,
        "anuityForeignCurrencyAmount": 1682.0397,
        "totalDomesticCurrencyAmount": 12435285.0834,
        "totalForeignCurrencyAmount": 103368.9533,
        "dti": 0.4941
    },
}
 ... and 33 others
 ]
}
```

I want to check first 35 objects (last one object is excluded from assertion) with my control json (also 35 objects). I want to check values as well properties is there exact number in each object.

I've started something like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def writeResponse = slurper.parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)

def data0 = writeResponse.data[0]
def data1 = writeResponse.data[1]
def data2 = writeResponse.data[2]
def data3 = writeResponse.data[3]

//for(i=0, i<36, i++){
//if(data[i].idCalculation == 111) return true
//if(data[i].idCalculationResult == 707) return true
//}


log.info(data0)
```

For sure, there is much cleaner way to compare two json "files" in soapui?

Comment: Let me guess... You are testing a new version of an already existing serviceoperation, and want to automate the testing, that the new service returns the same as the old one...? Or do you merely have actual JSON files, that contain the expected results for a number of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would JsonSlurpify both JSON files. (Same format, right?)

Assuming the result is ordered in the same way in both places, you should be able to simply loop over the entries. Something like:

```
def jsonFile1 = slurper.parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)
def jsonFile2 = slurper.parseText([whereEverYouHaveYourControlJsonFile])
for (def x=0; x<35; x++) {
    assert jsonFile1.data[x].idCalculation == jsonFile2.data[x].idCalculation
    assert jsonFile1.data[x].idCalculationResult== jsonFile2.data[x].idCalculationResult
    // etc... Repeat for each variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do an exact match between the documents (apart from the final element) or to just make sure that a JSON payload conforms to a particular schema? If it's the latter, then you can use a JSON schema to validate your payload. This will check the structure of your payload (including mandatory and optional elements) and the values (not necessarily exact values, but does a value meet a particular pattern).

For example, a minimal JSON schema that validates your payload would be:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Stack Overflow",
    "description": "Minimal JSON schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "idCalculation": {
                            "minimum": 0,
                            "maximum": 1000,
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "idCalculationResult": {
                            "minimum": 0,
                            "maximum": 1000,
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "exchangeRate": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0,
                            "pattern": "^[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{1}$"
                        },
                        "interestRate": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0,
                            "pattern": "^[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}$"
                        },
                        "anuityDomesticCurrencyAmount": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0
                        },
                        "anuityForeignCurrencyAmount": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0
                        },
                        "totalDomesticCurrencyAmount": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0,
                            "exclusiveMinimum": true
                        },
                        "totalForeignCurrencyAmount": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0
                        },
                        "dti": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 0
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "idCalculation",
                        "idCalculationResult",
                        "exchangeRate",
                        "interestRate",
                        "anuityDomesticCurrencyAmount",
                        "anuityForeignCurrencyAmount",
                        "totalDomesticCurrencyAmount",
                        "totalForeignCurrencyAmount",
                        "dti"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": ["data"]
}
```

It's up to you how exact you get with the patterns to validate the contents of your payload. See [Understanding JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html) for more details about JSON Schema.

If you have Ready API, there's a built-in [JSON Schema Compliance Assertion](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/assertions/reference/compliance/json-schema.html) where you can use this schema. If you have soapUI, you can call out to Groovy or Java to perform the schema validation for you. I use [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) and in my test cases the comparison boils down to:

`assert JsonValidatorUtils.isJsonValid(schemaFile, jsonPayload)`

All this might seem like a lot of work, but if you invest the time upfront you may end up with a generic solution you can reuse.

Comment: thanks for this code, for now I only want to check values from response with my control json file.

Comment: How do you use json-schema-validator maven project in SoapUI for the schema validation. I have the response schema and wanted to validate it against the API response in SoapUI. @craigcaulfield

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
...
def writeResponse = slurper.parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)
writeResponse.data.eachWithIndex{dat, idx->
    if(idx<35){
        assert dat.idCalculation == 111
        assert dat.idCalculationResult == 707
    }
}
```

Comment: close but not exactly. if you can see my response json, my values for example for properties idCalculation is always the same, but other properties are calculated, so in each set, there will be different values, which is ok, but I need to coomapre each set of values with my control json master set.